# Убрать запятые в SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю запрос чтобы мне получить комиссию с каждой валюты:
SELECT (received_currency, given_currency), commission, operation_type_id FROM transaction WHERE operation_type_id != 2

И получаю вот такой результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне не нужны запятые в столбце row, как я могу их убрать ?

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Очень интересно, но ничего непонятно.

Comment: `select concat(x, ', ', y)` для стандартного sql  и  trim сделать

Comment: а что хотели получить? `(a, b)` без всяких вызовов функций - это синтаксис Row Constructors. Попытка сделать `select (a,b)` так и должна выводиться как record. Но обычно это значит, что вывести хотели что-то другое

Comment: Получить желаемый результат получилось так:  select concat(x ,  y)